# Using gulp without global gulp //edit: and without linking to the bin js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

I have a gulpfile.js that runs through perfectly when typing `gulp` into the commandline.

All the `gulp` bash command really does is calling the specified js file in `package.json >> bin >> gulp` of the globally installed gulp.

Now I want to run the gulpfile without the globally installed gulp by simply typing `node gulpfile.js` which fails obviously and already has been mentioned quite often, despite gulp being installed locally and required at the beginning of the `gulpfile.js`

Using gulp without the cli tool would make it possible to use gulp as part of other npm plugins very easily.

**Note:**
Requiring another gulpfile.js works from an original gulpfile.js when this original gulpfile.js has been started via the gulp cli tool.

**Question:**
What is the best way of running/requiring gulp without the need for the global cli gulp tool (//edit: or linking to it locally)? e.g. being able to simply require it from another js file when gulp is only a locally installed dependency. (in other words starting gulp programmatically from inside JS without CLI intervention of any kind)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In package.json

```
"scripts": {
   "gulp": "gulp"  
},
```

And then this command `npm run gulp` 
Also npm provides the ability to pass extra parameters to your commands.
This is only the case for npm >= 2.0

Update: Without bin link

You can check the `node_modules/.bin/gulp`  or `node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js` file to see how you can start gulp (Line 129 is interesting)

I think this should work:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    console.log('do something');
});

gulp.start.apply(gulp, ['default']);
```

Comment: this also is another way of linking the CLI tool.

Comment: Yes, and since npm >= 2.0 you can also pass arguments to the CLI tool

Comment: Ps check node_modules/.bin/gulp

Answer (score 9):

When you install it locally (`npm install --save-dev gulp`) you can just run it by calling `./node_modules/.bin/gulp all`

Or you can define an `npm` script, and run it with `npm run gulp`

by adding this to `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "gulp": "gulp"
}
```

Comment: ok, but that is just another way of linking to the CLI tool, isn't it?

Comment: @philli yes but without the need to install it globally, you will only use the local installation in your projects `node_modules` directory. You need to install gulp somewhere otherwise you can run gulp.

Comment: But why is there the need to use the CLI at all, when I require gulp in the js file? I understand that gulp as dependency needs to be installed.

Comment: @philli Ah ok now I think get what you are asking. You want to start it programatically from inside your application.

Comment: yes :) Feel free to edit the question, if you know how to phrase it better.

Comment: You can check the node_modules/.bin/gulp file

Comment: ok, I'll try to find out what the CLI tool does exactly. However the solution should work by simply working with the required gulp package. e.g. something like:

`var gulp= require('gulp'); gulp.setMode('silent');`

Comment: @phlli  It's `gulp.start.apply(gulp, ['mytask']);`

Answer (score 9):

Meanwhile since npm >= 5.2.0. you can do it with 'npx':

```
npx gulp
```

It executes the binaries in ./node_modules/.bin

By the way, it has the ability to execute not installed tools which are only temporary installed, executed and then deleted.

Checkout the post from Kat Marchán: [Introducing npx: an npm package runner](https://medium.com/@maybekatz/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner-55f7d4bd282b)

Answer (score 5):

In your package.json add the following:

```
"scripts": {
  "gulp": "node ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js <task-name>" 
}
```

and run from command line by typing npm run gulp.

This removes the dependency on having gulp globally installed

Answer (score 4):

I think the most direct answer is the following:

```
node ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js
```

Yes, adding to your npm scripts works, but this doesn't help in situations like automated builds where you are trying to run a gulp task for existing code from a repo and you can't easily change package.json.

Generally speaking Sander Visser's answer is probably the "best", but this is the lowest level call that can be implemented anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Reiterating the answers above, but including the gulpfile location and a gulp command (in this case `build`. On Windows you can use the following:

`node node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js build --gulpfile "C:\my_project_location\gulpfile.js"`