# gulp command line tool not working

Tags: npm, gulp

I've recently setup gulp but although it appears to be (partially) working in my IDE it doesn't appear to work in the command line.

my package.json file is:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.14.0",
    "del": "^2.2.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-cssnano": "^2.1.2",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^3.0.3",
    "gulp-less": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-pixrem": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "run-sequence": "^1.2.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.8.0"
  }
}
```

These have been installed with `npm install`
(but note I haven't installed gulp globally (npm is installed via brew on OSX))

running `which gulp` however I get gulp not found?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can install gulp globally, do it

```
npm install -g gulp
```

(may require `sudo` - use sudo, or google "fix npm permissions")

If you can't install gulp globally, there are some solutions here:
[Using gulp without global gulp //edit: and without linking to the bin js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33018779/using-gulp-without-global-gulp-edit-and-without-linking-to-the-bin-js-file)

Comment: thanks that fixed it. Is that the best way to use it. (Normally it's not recommended to install with sudo - but I'm not sure if doing a global npm install is quite the same?)

Comment: Yes, installing gulp globally (and then again via the project's package.json) is the usual route. Running a command with `sudo` gives that command super-user permissions. In theory that could let it install malware. In this case it's more about the idea of avoiding `sudo` when possible just as a good habit. Tweaking your setup to not require `sudo` is pretty easy (lots of write ups out there).